# where could I find training.pt / test.pt

Tags: pytorch, mnist

In the [Pytorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torchvision/datasets/mnist.html#MNIST) for MNIST I read:

> root (string): Root directory of dataset where `MNIST/processed/training.pt`
> and  `MNIST/processed/test.pt` exist.

Where could I find these two files `traing.pt`, `test.pt`? And what are their format?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `pytorch 1.x+`, The constructor of torchvision.datasets.MNIST follows this signature:

```
torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root, train=True, transform=None, target_transform=None, download=False)
```

The easiest way to get the dataset is to set `download=True`, that way it will automatically download and store `training.pt` and `test.pt`. Assuming a local install, it will by default store them somewhere like `.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision/`, although you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Thank you for reply. By the way, Is there any document to describe these two files' format?

Comment: @bingchen Those are binary formats. I think that there are very few applications that would require you to investigate what they are. Usually it's better for you to load them via `your_module.load_state_dict`. If you still want to see the details, have a look into https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/serialization.py. Basically, it seems that they use python's `pickle` module internally.